# How to run a trained keras model in simulink?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, time-series, simulink

I have developed a Keras LSTM model to predict a time series signal for me. Now I need to use this model in MATLAB Simulink. Any help?

I have a MATLAB R2017b which does not have the toolbox for importing Keras models.